# Arrays dont add up

Tags: python, numpy

Troubleshooting some code I am writing and the code isn't adding up properly. Am I doing something wrong? The last line should have the same output as the 3rd line

[image: The code]

Comment: It's overflowing.

Comment: Addition of two numpy arrays with dtype `uint8` is modulo 256.

Comment: Please post plain text, not images.

Comment: The maximum value of a `uint8` is `255`. How do you expect to fit `302` into that?

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for clarifying